# PLSQL Oracle Command does not allow multiple exceptions in the same command

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, plsql

I am storing the following script in a C# `OracleCommand`. When I execute it I get

> "encountered the symbol "/" when expecting one of the following: " errors.

I am trying to mass create a lot of tables while checking to see if they exist first and dropping if they do.

```sql
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE allexact';
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
CREATE TABLE allexact
(
t_long long NULL,
t_binFloat binary_float NULL,
t_binDbl binary_double NULL,
t_rowid rowid NULL,
t_date date NULL,
t_blob BLOB NULL,
t_CLOB CLOB NULL,
t_NCLOB NCLOB NULL
)';
END;//
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE chr_1';
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
CREATE TABLE chr_1
(
chr_1 char(1) NULL,
chr_2 char(2) NULL,
chr_3 char(3) NULL,
chr_4 char(4) NULL,
...
chr_60 char(60) NULL
)';
END;//
```

This command works fine in plsql developer, but not when being executed as a command in C#. If I only have 1 exception at the bottom of all of the code it works fine, but as soon as the exception is hit, then (as expected) the rest of the code is skipped. How do I put multiple exception statements into a plsql command that is stored in a C# OracleCommand variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `OracleCommand`, You can execute only 1 SQL statement or 1 Stored Procedure or 1 Anonymous block (your case). But you passed 2 anonymous blocks. Hence the error. Try pack all into 1 block

```sql
begin
   begin 
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE . . . 
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE . . . 
   exception when
   end;

   begin
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE . . . 
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE . . . 
   exception when
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Awesome....Killing the "//" and wrapping in a begin/end seems to have done the trick. Thank you!

Comment: @JacobAlley nice question